# Processamento de pagamentos para mais de uma API

Tags: php, api, pagamento-online

Estou desenvolvendo um site que busca reservas de passagens aéreas através da API do *Decolar.com* e busca hotéis pela API do *Booking.com*.

Minha dúvida é, tem como eu unificar o processo de pagamento? Por exemplo, o usuário paga uma única vez (valor total de hotel+voo) e é repassado para o processador de pagamentos dessas plataformas.

Answer (score -3):

Você pode usar uma terceira API que recebe o pagamento dos seus clientes como PagSeguro ou Mercadopago. Assim você recebe o valor total, e faz os pagamentos no momento em que a API acusar a conclusão da transferência.